# problemas con el insert PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes mi duda es
tengo un insert en php la cuestion es que manda los datos pero no los guarda en el formulario
asi es como me los arroja
string(230) "INSERT INTO registro (nombre,apellidos,correo,usuario,repassword,empleado,rol) VALUES ('RUSAs','Ramirezzv','houston25b@hotmail.com','pruebas3','$2y$10$pL7DMaNFiZBRIUHc7TGnhuETPYx10PnYUpHd1Hel7tzh4EdTMBJ46','0876543','1')"
y lo valide en mysql y si los guarda pero no en mi form

aca esta mi codigo
me funcionaba bien pero esta mañana desperte y dejo sin dejarme insertar ningun registro mas

```
<?php
     
 if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
            include ("conecta.php");
           
            if (!$conexion) {
               
                $msg="Conexión imposible. Revise las credenciales de conexión";    
            } else {
                

            $nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
            $apellidos=!empty($_POST['apellidos']) ? $_POST['apellidos'] : NULL;
            $correo=!empty($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;
            $usuario=!empty($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : NULL;
            $repassword=!empty($_POST['repassword']) ? $_POST['repassword'] : NULL;
            $levely=!empty($_POST['levely']) ? $_POST['levely'] : NULL;
            $empleado=!empty($_POST['empleado']) ? $_POST['empleado'] : NULL;

                $hashPassword = password_hash($repassword,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
               
                
                $nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
    
                if($usuario && $repassword  && $nombre) { 
                    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM registro';
                  
                    $rec = $conexion->query($sql); 
                    
                    $verificar_usuario = FALSE;
                   
                     while($result = $rec->fetch_object()) { 
                        if($result->usuario == $usuario) { 
                            $verificar_usuario = TRUE; 
                         
                                break; 
                        }
                    } 
               
    if(!$verificar_usuario) { 
    
    if($repassword == $repassword) { 
     
        $query= "INSERT INTO registro (nombre,apellidos,correo,usuario,repassword,empleado,rol) VALUES
         ('$nombre','$apellidos','$correo','$usuario','$hashPassword','$empleado','$levely')";

            if ($conexion->query($sql) && $conexion->affected_rows > 0) {
            /*echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Usted se ha registrado correctamente.");
            window.location.href="index.php";
            </script>';
            */
            
            
            
        } else {
            $msg="Error en la inserción";
        }
    } else { 
        $msg="Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente."; 
    } 
    } else {
    /* 
        No se entiende mucho esta parte de la lógica ¿?
    */
    $msg="Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente."; 
    } 
    
    } else {
    $msg="Por favor llene todos los campos. Faltan datos en el POST";
    }
    }
    
    } else {
    $msg="";  
    }
   
    echo $msg;



var_dump($query);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No te lo esta dejando guardar por que ROL seguro que en tu DB es de tipo INT o numérico y lo estas gurdando como tipo String proba algo asi:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO registro (nombre,apellidos,correo,usuario,repassword,empleado,rol) VALUES
  ('$nombre','$apellidos','$correo','$usuario','$hashPassword','$empleado',$levely)";
```

Osea todo dato que reciba tu DB numérico sácale las comillas como hice con levely... proba y después conta como fue!

Comment: asi lo tenia
------INSERT INTO registro (nombre,apellidos,correo,usuario,repassword,empleado,rol) VALUES ('RUSAs','Ramirezzv','houston25b@hotmail.com','pruebas3','$2y$10$8NsGFUzA1fiX0LstpoHdFeBWEvt6/dL2CBBf/WcJhnrS/h43oAohy','0876543',1)

Comment: y no me inserto datos

Comment: Inserta esto en tu DB en phpmyadmin: 

'RUSAs','Ramirezzv','houston25b@hotmail.com','pruebas3','$2y$10$8NsGFUzA1fiX0LstpoHdFeBWEvt6/dL2CBBf/WcJhnrS/h43oAohy','0876543',1

Y fijate que error sale

Comment: si me lo inserta

Comment: bueno ya sabemos que al menos el query del insert esta bien... ahora el problema es que no te muestre el usuario por pantalla ??? o cual es el resultado final que buscas?

Comment: esta bien el resultado lo que busco es que me lo inserte en la tabla pero me manda un script que agrege que dice datos ingresados correctamente el problema es que no me aparece el registro en la BD

Comment: proba llamando a la conexion include ("conecta.php"); debajo de if($repassword == $repassword) {

Comment: string(228) "INSERT INTO registro (nombre,apellidos,correo,usuario,repassword,empleado,rol) VALUES ('RUSAs','Ramirezzv','houston25b@hotmail.com','pruebas3','$2y$10$t.Te5q0LoIsweYCZ02je4e1BhzCEyhWsHE/8ryYlz2N/PcC30Og3G','0876543',1)"

Comment: Algo esta fallando en la logica, xq si te inserta en phpmyadmin... mira.. proba  $nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL; remplazando en todos lados el !empty por isset osea
 $nombre=isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : '';
$apellidos=isset($_POST['apellidos']) ? $_POST['apellidos'] : '';
etc... si no te lo inserta es xq estan llegando NULL o vacios los datos

Comment: y si esta nulo?

Comment: si llega nulo es que del formulario donde ingresas el registro estas pasando o mal algun NAME que recibis por POST y por ende al no recibir nada no te deja insertarlo en la tabla, pero como me decis que si te inserto y te mustra por pantalla eso, entonces debe andar por ahi el problema de logica